# How to connect to my TuneIn account in the Windows 8 Metro App?

Tags: windows-8

In the Windows 8 store they offer the [TuneIn App](http://tunein.com/). How do I connect this app to my TuneIn account so I do not have to add my favourite radio stations manually?

(At least I can not see the "obvious" login form somewhere, but maybe I am missing something here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To login to an existing account (or create a new one):

1. Press <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or use the
   hotspot(s) on the right side of your screen to bring up the charms
   bar.
2. Click settings.
3. Click `Sign In / Sign Up`

**Remember:** Settings in the charms bar is contextual (as is search). It's the first place to look for this type of question.

[image]

Comment: i knew it was something obvious. yah, i missed the charms-per-tile part completely.

Comment: @akira, I've done it as well. Two more upvotes and I'm done lvl 1 :)

Comment: so, you think this is a funny game, huh? :)

Comment: I guess I am not used to Windows 8 yet. Thank you for the guidance. I signed in and I now see a column for "favorites". Alas, when I click on the "Shows" tile or the "Stations" tile, nothing happens